# jquery selector with >

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
<tr num="1"></tr>
<tr id="a" num="2"></tr>
<tr num="3"></tr>
<tr num="2"></tr>
<tr num="1"></tr>
</table>

$('#a').nextUntil('tr[num > 1]')
```

How can I implement the above query with JQuery 1.4.2 in which the first parameter for nextUntil() is selector and not JQuery object?

I was thinking on something like:

```
$(some tr id).nextall().filter(function () {return $(this).attr('num') > 1;});
```

But if there are many tr it could take some time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would `$('tr[num!=1]')` work for you?

Comment: is it always going to be num > 1? Or will it change to num > 2, num > 3, etc?

Comment: and are you always looking for just all the next that are equal to or less (which is what `nextUntil` would return)?

Comment: It'll be num > x where is a variable, and yes I always looking for larger than x

Answer (score -1):

You could the .each function:

```
$("tr").each(function(index, value)
            {
              if ($(value).attr('num') > 1)
              {
                // do sth. with it
              }
            });
```

Or maybe also by jquery additional greater than selector

```
:gt(index)
```

But this should be really tricky, filtering this way.

Comment: index will not work since I'm filtering according to the num attribute and no location.

Comment: you should not use :gt inside the .each loop. It should be an one-line alternative to a loop. That just the name 'index' caught from the official jQuery docu. As I wrote, it woulde be complex to do it that way. But the .each should work for your task.